# QGIS 3.4 - Problem adding layers with QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer()

Tags: gis, qgis

i'm trying to add layer from Postgis into a Qgis project. My script seems to work because I've no error but the layers are not added to the project. Each of the table I try to add have a unique key.

Here is my script :

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
try:
    uri.setConnection("my_host", "my_port", "my_dbase_name", "my_user", "my_password")
except:
    'Unable to connect database !'

uri.setDataSource("my_schema", "my_table", "geom","","my_unique_id")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "my_layer_name", "my_user_name")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

I don't know where the problem come from ? If anybody as an idea or see an evident error ... i'm interested in.

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what is returned when you create the layer, it will be `None` if an error occurs. I also think you need to specify the driver you want to use (`postgres`) not your user name.

I would use code like:

```
tablename = "thetable"
geometrycol = "geom"

from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceUri
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("host", "5432", "db", "user", "pass")
uri.setDataSource ("schema", tablename, geometrycol)
vlayer=QgsVectorLayer (uri.uri(False), tablename, "postgres")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```